# Difference between G2 = G .* G and G2 = G * G in Matlab GPU Computing

Tags: matlab

What's the difference between `G2 = G .* G` and `G2 = G * G` in the following codes? And why I get with first code GPU Load 100% and with the second I get GPU Load and Memory Controller Load sensors both at 100% on gpu-z ?

```
X = rand(5000, 'double');
G = gpuArray(X);
classUnderlying(G)          % Returns 'single'

for m = 1:5000
G2 = G .* G .* G .* G;         % Performed on GPU
end

whos G2                     % Result on GPU
```

---

```
X = rand(5000, 'double');
G = gpuArray(X);
classUnderlying(G)          % Returns 'single'

for m = 1:5000
G2 = G * G * G * G;         % Performed on GPU
end

whos G2                     % Result on GPU
```

Answer (score 2):

There is matrix multiplication (`mtimes`) and elementwise multiplication (`times`)

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/times.html

Answer (score 1):

The operator `*` is used for matrix multiplication where the dimensions must match. somtimes you may want to use element by elemeny multiplication or (Element-wise multiplication) in which we use the operator `.*`.

```
a = 1 1 1
    1 1 1
    1 1 1

b = 2 2 2
    2 2 2
    2 2 2

a * b = 6 6 6
        6 6 6
        6 6 6

a .* b = 2 2 2
         2 2 2
         2 2 2
```

Comment: I've added another question, can you answer also that one?

Comment: @FormlessCloud Simply cause the number of operations in the second one is 2*n times of the first one ( matrix multiplication is much more complicated)